# Include GET variables in .htaccess redirect

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Here is my .htaccess code:

```
#Rewrite settings
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

#Remove index.php from url
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /(.*)index\.php($|\ |\?)
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L]

#Add trailing slash
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1/ [L,R=301]

#Make entire url variable
RewriteRule ^(.*/)$ /index.php?path=$1 [R=301]
```

I would like to redirect all requests for files name "index.php" in any of the sub directories to the root "index.php" with the path as a get variable. So:

```
http://mywebsite.com/this/is/the/path/index.php
becomes:
http://mywebsite.com/index.php?path=this/is/the/path/
```

This currently works. However, the problem is that if the original url has GET variables in it, they are removed and not included in the path. So:

```
http://mywebsite.com/this/is/the/path/index.php?get=variables
should become:
http://mywebsite.com/index.php?path=this/is/the/path/%3Fget%3Dvariables
```

How can this be done? I am new to URL rewriting and can't seem to get my code to behave in this way.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Everything you need to know about regular expressions can be found here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to add query string append (QSA) flag like this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*/)$ /index.php?path=$1 [R=301,QSA]
```